# How to avoid urlencoding in python post request?

Tags: python, python-3.x, encoding, request

I have this request:

```
url 'https://www.myapi.com/post/?text=%40.gamerboy.0+%40buddythegame+%40monster._.360+%40medoingnothin2000000+%40bryansubz&text_extra=[%7B%22start%22:0,%22end%22:12%22type%22:3%7D]&_signature=_02B4Z6wo01101Lo5vewAAIDCZn3AnH8dm3y6OblAAE5xa2'

response2 = requests.post(url, headers=headers, verify=False, proxies=proxies, timeout=10)
```

But it always failed. When I debug it. I found the URL in request somehow replaced and encoded the chars of [ ]'s to %5B and %5D !

As images below:

https://gyazo.com/bb3e02773067adab61f4309ff1ff64ee

https://gyazo.com/6f714835302948cbf4329bf553c33898

How to prevent that from happening?

Tried, to use payload, but failed attempt.

Please advise, Thank you
//henrik

Comment: Isn't that correct though? It shouldn't leave them as `[` or`]` as that would be invalid for a URL.

Comment: @PeterWood It's not invalid, even if its incorrect, how to keep them []'s without encoding them? Thanks.

Comment: But it has to. Otherwise the URL would be invalid. Why do you want an invalid URL?

Comment: It's not invalid.

Comment: Okay, it's not invalid, but it's unwise. See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13500078/1084416

Comment: @PeterWood OK how to use it unwise? and prevent replacement?

Comment: Still not fixed.

Comment: If you want nonstandard behaviour, you should implement yourself the relative functions (you have low level network control also in standard pythons). And when API works differently if you try in a browser or on command line... we have a problem.